# simple syntax help for newbie

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have searched and not found any type of answer for this but when I try it in my phpmyadmin it tells me that the syntax is wrong. Could someone take a quick look and let me know what possibly could be wrong with this please:

```
UPDATE wellness_rsform_properties 
WHERE PropertyName = 'REQUIRED' 
AND PropertyValue = 'NO' 
REPLACE  (PropertyValue, 'NO', 'YES');
```

I would really appreciate any feedback!

Thanks,
Doug

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE wellness_rsform_properties
SET PropertyValue = 'YES'
WHERE PropertyName = 'REQUIRED' AND PropertyValue = 'NO'
```

`REPLACE` function is not necessary because you compare `PropertyValue = 'NO'`. If you wanted to replace all occurrences of `NO` with `YES`, `REPLACE` would be applicable:

```
UPDATE wellness_rsform_properties
SET PropertyValue = REPLACE (PropertyValue, 'NO', 'YES')
WHERE PropertyName = 'REQUIRED' AND PropertyValue like '%NO%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Should be something like

```
UPDATE wellness_rsform_properties 
SET PropertyValue = REPLACE('NO', 'YES') 
WHERE PropertyName = 'REQUIRED' AND PropertyValue = 'NO'
```

How ever, you don't need to use replace, because you know new value of column, just update it:

```
UPDATE wellness_rsform_properties 
SET PropertyValue = 'YES' 
WHERE PropertyName = 'REQUIRED' AND PropertyValue = 'NO'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE wellness_rsform_properties 
set PropertyValue = REPLACE (PropertyValue, 'NO', 'YES')
where PropertyName = 'REQUIRED' AND PropertyValue = 'NO';
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Unfortunately I received this error : Error

SQL query:

WHERE PropertyName = 'REQUIRED' AND PropertyValue = 'NO'

MySQL said: Documentation
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where PropertyName = 'REQUIRED' AND PropertyValue = 'NO'' at line 1

Comment: That is because there is a semicolon before the WHERE clause. It should be at the end.

Comment: Ah I missed that `;`. Fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you seem to be trying

```
UPDATE wellness_rsform_properties
SET PropertyValue = 'YES'
WHERE PropertyName ='REQUIRED'
AND PropertyValue = 'NO';
```

Follow syntax

```
UPDATE <tables>
SET <field = value>
WHERE <criteria for which rows to update>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean?

```
UPDATE wellness_rsform_properties 
SET PropertyValue = 'YES'
WHERE PropertyName = 'REQUIRED' AND PropertyValue = 'NO';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE wellness_rsform_properties
SET PropertyValue = REPLACE(PropertyValue, 'NO', 'YES') 
WHERE PropertyName = 'REQUIRED' 
AND PropertyValue = 'NO';
```

I believe this is what you are looking for.